# I would like to know how can i do tab spaces after a word so that the pattern that comes after that would be align with each other

Tags: php, css, whitespace

I would like to know how to do tab spaces after a word. The output shown is what i currently have. However i want to do it so that even though the word thai is shorter than the word cantonese, I want the circles after them to start at the same point so it will look more organized. 
Below are my php codes to generate the language which could be 'thai', 'english' etc. and if the level of language is proficient, it will show 1 circle so on and so forth.

```
for($a = 0; $a < $count; $a++)
    {
        $b = $languagelevel[$a][0];
        echo $b;


        if($languagelevel[$a][1] == "Proficient")
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++)
            {
                echo "<div class='language1'></div>";
            }
        }
        else if($languagelevel[$a][1] == "Good")
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
            {
                echo "<div class='language2'></div>";
            }
        }
        else if($languagelevel[$a][1] == "Very Good")
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
            {
                echo "<div class='language3'></div>";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
            {
                echo "<div class='language3'></div>";
            }
        }

        echo "<br>";

    }
```

Below are my css codes for the circles.

```
.language1
        {
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            padding: 3px;
            display:inline-block;
            background-color: red;
            border: 2px solid #666;
            margin-left: 5px;

            font: 20px Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .language2
        {
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            padding: 3px;
            display:inline-block;
            background-color: orange;
            border: 2px solid #666;
            margin-left: 5px;

            font: 20px Arial, sans-serif;
        }

        .language3
        {
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            padding: 3px;
            display:inline-block;
            background-color: green;
            border: 2px solid #666;
            margin-left: 5px;

            font: 20px Arial, sans-serif;
        }
```

[image: This is the output that i currently have.]
And this is my current output.

Comment: We need to see the output HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML ignores white spaces between tags, so it is not possible to use tabs. Instead, it would be better if you add a container to your course title, and fix a width for that.

Currently, I think your HTML output is like this:

```
<div>Cantonese<div class='language1'></div></div>
```

If you change the part where the course name is echoed to the html to include a container, then add a `min-width` to that container, you can simulate tabs.

So change

```
echo $b;
```

To something like

```
echo "<span class='container'>". $b . "</span>";
```

And then add some CSS like below:

```
.container {
  min-width: 50px; /* Here you set the width of the 'tab' */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This will result in something like the following:

```css
.container {
  min-width: 100px; /* Here you set the width of the 'tab' */
  display: inline-block;
}

.language1, .language2 {
  display: inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<div><span class="container">Cantonese</span><div class="language1">Language 1</div></div>
<div><span class="container">Thai</span><div class="language2">Language 2</div></div>
```

Comment: But what does the inline-block does? why do we have to do that?

Comment: @Samuel `inline` makes it inline, and `block` means we can add a width to it

Answer (score -1):

You can use Html table with border none, when you don't know the maximum length of the label( in your case Cantonese, Thai), you can use table

```html
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Cantonese</td>
    <td>**</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Teo chew</td>
    <td>****</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Thai</td>
    <td>****</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!